# Is there a way to install an .otf font on OpenSuse

Tags: fonts, rpm, opensuse

I was wondering, is there any way to install an .otf font on OpenSuse ?  
Plus I made a lot of research about the love story between OpenSuse and fonts, I find out that some .rpm packages contains fonts.  
And the rpm man didn’t help me a lot..  
I know that some fonts managers exist, but I cant be root on my Suse, don’t ask me why, I got my reasons. So please, give me some unroot tips.

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have root access, you can install a font only for your account (not system wide).
To do that, just copy the .otf file in the `~/.fonts/` directory.

```
$ cp filename.otf ~/.fonts/
```